# D3.js "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error with Play Framework

Tags: d3.js, playframework, playframework-2.0

i have code that works outside of Play Framework but gives me errors when i implement the code in Play. When i bind d3.js it gives me the following error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Object.ms [as extent] (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> ((index):103)
    at p.call (d3.v4.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.e (d3.v4.min.js:2)"
```

Why does this happen? I definitely integrated the sources correctly. All other sources work perfectly.

EDIT: Play Framework version 2.6.6 and sbt version 0.13.5

Requested code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {


        var svg = d3.select("svg"),
                margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
                width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
                g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

        var x = d3.scaleTime()
                .rangeRound([0, width]);

        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
                .rangeRound([height, 0]);

        var line = d3.line()
                .x(function (d) {
                    return x(d.date);
                })
                .y(function (d) {
                    return y(d.close);
                });

        d3.tsv("/assets/images/data.tsv", function (d) {
            d.date = parseTime(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
            return d;
        }, function (error, data) {

            x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
                return d.date;
            }));
            y.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
                return d.close;
            }));

            g.append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("fill", "#000")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
                    .attr("x", 6)
                    .attr("dx", "1em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "begin   ")
                    .text("time")
                    .select(".domain")
                    .remove();

            g.append("g")
                    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("fill", "#000")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                    .attr("y", 6)
                    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
                    .text("Price ($)");

            g.append("path")
                    .datum(data)
                    .attr("fill", "none")
                    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
                    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
                    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
                    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
                    .attr("d", line);
        });

    }

    </script>
```

This is the d3 script that is on the bottom of the html file outside of the body.

In the body itself i have amongst other things this SVG object that is used:

```
<svg id="svg" width="960" height="500"></svg>
```

As i said this works perfectly outside of play. But if i start play it just throws that error.

Comment: Can you post example code? From this I can tell you that you're trying to call onto the property (array,  object, or something else) that still hasn't been fully initialized.

Comment: I edited it @mutantkeyboard

Comment: Ok. Two things I'd try. First one is go with jQuery, and type: 
```javascript
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "document loaded" );
    });
 
    $( window ).on( "load", function() {
        console.log( "window loaded" );
    });
```
to make sure I have both DOM loaded and document ready. Another thing would be the TSV file. Is the `/assets` folder subfolder in the current folder, or above? In that case you'll have to use `d3.tsv('../assets/...);`

Comment: Where exactly do i put in the jQuery code? The data.tsv is in the folder public->images->data.tsv, where public is the highest hierarchy, the html file is in app->views->d3->index.scala.html

Comment: Aha, so this is the view file. Ok. Try cutting out the JS from the index.html completely, and put it into the public->assets->javascript and name it whatever you like, e.g `myscript.js`. Then pull it into the index like `<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/myscript.js")"></script>`, and then replace the d3 code for reading the dir above (in your case images) `d3.tsv(../images/data.tsv)` and see if the error persists. I didn't program with Play that much, but might be an issue with routes or even read permissions.